# Unicode in Python for Kannada language

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to work with Unicode for Kannada language, I am working with Python 2.7 when typed the following code:

```
print u'\u0cb5\u0ccd\u0c87'
```

The output is ವ್ಇ but I expected to print "vi" in Kannada??

Comment: I don't know anything about Kannada, but it seems like what you tried should print some characters and it does, why would you expect it to print "vi" ?

Comment: What is '"vi" in kannada'? What output do you expect?

Comment: "vi" is the sound that reperesented by the character i am trying to print

Answer (score 3):

I believe you've not encoded your string properly. I expect this is what you want:

```
>>> print u'\u0cb5\u0CBF'
ವಿ
```

What you did was to output (using the full names that Unicode assigns to these characters):

- KANNADA LETTER VA
- KANNADA SIGN VIRAMA
- KANNADA LETTER I

I can see the logic in this but that's not how Unicode works. The virama should be used only for consonant clusters or if you have a sequence that ends in a consonant. To combine syllables with vowels you have to use the syllable together with a *combining* form of the vowel:

- KANNADA LETTER VA
- KANNADA VOWEL SIGN I

The KANNADA VOWEL SIGN I is a *combining* form of the letter "I" whereas KANNADA LETTER I is a non-combining form of the same letter.

I suggest reading the [chapter 9 of the Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch09.pdf) for a complete explanation of how to deal with South-Asian scripts. [Chapter 10](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch10.pdf) can also be useful.

Comment: Thank you for kind response I Will read the suggestions and get back

Answer (score 1):

`0cb5` is [Unicode Character 'KANNADA LETTER VA' (U+0CB5)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0cb5/index.htm) ವ . So Python is correct to print ವ್ಇ.

Answer (score 1):

It should be printing the Kannada characters VA, VIRAMA, I according the the latest sheet from [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0C80.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use font that have kannada symbols you'll get boxes.

Got this after installing [lohit-fonts](https://fedorahosted.org/lohit) on my gentoo box:

[image: after fonts installed].